# using redis in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-redis

I have a default Express app, and my routes index.js file looks like this:

```
var user = require('../models/user');

exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express', object: obj });
};
```

Now, suppose in my app.js file the `client` object that is the redis client connected to my redis-server, and I would like to be able to use that client object in my user model, for example to avoid repeated login attempts. How can I be able to access that object in my user model? Here is the code for that model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email:    { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  name:     { type: String, required: true }
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

exports.canLogin = function(mIn, pIn, next){
  User.findOne({
    email: mIn
  }, function(err, user){
    if(!err){
      if(user.password == pIn)
        next(true);
        else next(false);
    } else next(false);
  });
};
```

Comment: I don't follow your question and where redis fits in.

Comment: suppose that in my canLogin function I want to check for something in redis. How do I access the 'client' object from there?

Comment: Is your 'client' in the session?

Comment: Where is the `client` object created? In a module, exported? `canLogin` is just JavaScript, so I don't follow what you're trying to do. This doesn't seem to have any connection to MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store your client in the session, you can use [connect-redis](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis) to setup session storage in express like so

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);

app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
  store: new RedisStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379,
    db: 2,
    pass: 'RedisPASS'
  }),
  secret: '1234567890QWERTY'
}));
```

Now, you can access the session like this `req.session.WHATEVER`

([And you can do the same thing with mongo.](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions))

If you just want some redis storage available when processing the request, you can use [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) directly. There are plenty of examples on github